# How to create a small form into a view in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml

How to create a small form into a view equal to the one highlighted in **red** in WPF/XAML

[image]

#### edit

and how to link when i create the new Option on press the button OK updates the Options and select this new option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx)

```
<Popup Name="Popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AddButton}" 
                       StaysOpen="False">
                    ... Add content here ...
                </Popup>
```